# discord py error while making help command

Tags: python, discord.py

i have this error
`Expected coroutine function, not 'Command'`
and the code is for an help command

```
async def help(ctx, command_name=None):
    reactions = ["⬅️", "➡️"]

    embed = discord.Embed(title="         Help Command",description="Show The Help Command", color=0x87CEEB)
    embed.set_author(name="Gaming Bot", icon_url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/Loading_2.gif")
    embed.add_field(name="Member Text Commands", value="Help\nId\nInfo\nPing\nPoll", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Member Voice Commands", value="Join\nDisconnect", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Admin Commands", value="Prefix\nMute\nBan\nUnban\nClear\nKick", inline=False)
    oh_cool = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await oh_cool.add_reaction(reactions[0])
    await oh_cool.add_reaction(reactions[1])
```

Comment: Can you please add the **full** traceback?

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 151, in <module>
    async def help1(ctx, command_name=None):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 506, in decorator
    return Loop(func, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 76, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Expected coroutine function, not {0.__name__!r}.'.format(type(self.coro)))
TypeError: Expected coroutine function, not 'Command'```

Comment: Edit your question, don't post the error in the comments

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add a help command, as there is already one. just do this `@bot.command(name='test', help='[help message]')`
and then just do !help and it will show the commands and the help message.